# Where to put timeout operator in Redux Observable fetching epic

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I would like to put a timeout operator in my fetching epic that cancels the api call after given duration. Where would I put the operator in the code example below? Is my attempt correct? Doesn't work as hoped.

```
const fetchingEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType('FETCH_DATA')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      fromPromise(
        axios.post(`/url`, payload)
      )
        .map(response => ({
          type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
          data: response.data
        }))
        .timeout(5000)
        .catch(error =>
          Observable.of({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_ERROR',
            error
          })
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this tutorial](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeout.html) I think that timeout has to be directly below `fromPromise`:

```
const fetchingEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType('FETCH_DATA')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      fromPromise(
        axios.post(`/url`, payload)
      )
        .timeout(5000)
        .map(response => ({
          type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
          data: response.data
        }))
        .catch(error =>
          Observable.of({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_ERROR',
            error
          })
        )
    );
```